# Python - DLL load failed while importing open3d

Tags: python, dll, open3d

I've recently started to learn and play with Python. I use PyCharm, windows 10, Python 3.8.
I want to use a library called open3d. Thing is, every time I want to use it I have this error :

```
File "C:/Users/XXXX/PycharmProjects/cloud/demo-main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import open3d
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\cloud\venv\lib\site-packages\open3d\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from open3d.win32 import *
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\cloud\venv\lib\site-packages\open3d\win32\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    globals().update(importlib.import_module('open3d.win32.32b.open3d').__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\cloud\venv\lib\site-packages\open3d\win32\32b\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    globals().update(importlib.import_module('open3d.win32.32b.open3d').__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing open3d: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

So it's seems that Python is not able to locate/use that library. Now I've done my research and it seems that people get it fixed by installling microsoft redistrib but it doesn't work for me.
I really don't know how to fix this issue, if you have any idea, please let me now. (as i said I'm new to Python so maybe the fix is obvious)

Thanks you !

Comment: I'm having this problem moving to Windows Pro (from Enterprise). Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python in anaconda/miniconda environment than open anaconda prompt and execute

```
conda install -c open3d-admin open3d
```

Otherwise if you've downloaded python interpreter as standalone(i.e., without anaconda/miniconda) than open cmd and execute:
(Note that you must have python added in your system's Environment Variable. If not, than search windows for Environment Variable than paste path to your python installation in Path and save. Restart cmd)

```
pip3 install open3d
```

or

```
pip install --user open3d
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install --user open3d
```

Although this works for me but if this doesn't work for you than make sure that you have updated Visual Studio.
For this visit [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and install x86 and x64 packages in "Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" section.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I have updated Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. As I expected, open3d is already installed : Requirement already satisfied: open3d-python in c:\users\XXXX\pycharmprojects\cloud\venv\lib\site-packages (0.3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by deleting Python and PyCharm. I nstalled Miniconda instead and it worked.